# how to access virtual host outside

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-mint

I have this on my Apache 2 file "example.com.conf". I am only able to access it only by IP, but when I try to access it for the server name always I got the following error:

> Network Error (dns_server_failure)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin myemail
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias www.example.com

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.03 (X64)

I try to access this on a machine with Windows 8.1.

Comment: Have you add the entry in host file with domain name?

Comment: Did you mean in /etc/host? Yes i have it, i think so, my file hosts look lile :   Ip adresss <www.example.com>, or if you think something diferent please gime a example

Comment: yes, add the ip and yourdomain in hosts file , after check with ping <domain> then check in browser.

Comment: after do ping it works, but when i check in my browser it doesnt works and shows me the following :                                                             Network Error (dns_server_failure)

Your request could not be processed because an error occurred contacting the DNS server.
The DNS server may be temporarily unavailable, or there could be a network problem.

Comment: once try to add ubuntu server ip as a DNS in your windows 8 box. let me know...